# Splitting $^ in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rules in my Makefile:

```
appfile appfile.symbols:
    build-the-app

distribute: appfile appfile.symbols
    push -flag1 appfile -flag2 appfile.symbols
```

I would like to exchange `push -flag1 appfile -flag2 appfile.symbols` to instead use the dependencies retrieved from `$^` like `push -flag1 $^1 -flag2 $^2`

Is there any way of splitting $^ in order to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first prerequisite is in `$<`.  You can use the [`word`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) function in GNU make to get others (or for all of them if you prefer):

```
distribute: appfile appfile.symbols
        push -flag1 $< -flag2 $(word 2,$^)
```

Answer (score 2):

When dependencies have a certain pattern, you can use `filter` and `filter-out`; e.g.

```
distribute: ...
          push -flag1 $(filter-out %.symbols,$^) -flag2 $(filter %.symbols,$^)
```

Comment: thanks! both answers fit my needs, sadly I can only accept one of them :(